# PHP Registry prevents content assist

Tags: php, registry, content-assist

I have created a standard Registry class. The registry can then return a new or already created instance of a class by using:

```
$classObject = $registry->getInstance(Namespace\subdirectories\ClassName);
```

My project is set up with namespaces, so that is the typical syntax.
All works well, except IDEs like Eclipse luna will no longer have Content Assist, meaning pressing ctrl+space will no longer pop up a screen with the classes public methods.

Has anyone run into this situation before? How did you restore content assist functionality as best as you could? Alternatively, if you could not restore the functionality, what did you do so programming remained somewhat still practical within the project?

Comment: Anyone? I'm surprised there's nobody asking the same question on the internet, and all sites that have registry tutorials have no mention of how to preserve IDE content-assist functionality, not even in the comment sections. Would really appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by using PHPDoc type hinting for my IDE

Example

```
/**
/* @var \FullClassNamespace\
*/
$private $someVar;

public function __construct() {
    $this->someVar = registry->getClassinstance(fullnamespace);

    $someVar-> (autocomplete works)
}
```

It is worth noticing that in some IDEs doing an inline type hinting won't work, as in /** @var namespace */. The initial /** and ending */ must be in separated lines